# Misleading category title in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

This category is named “mine”. It is a bit misleading since it actually shows what rooms I’m in, not what rooms I own:

> [image: Misleading category title in action]

This suggests that I own The Nineteenth byte, which I do not.

Maybe this could be changed?

Comment: This is the name used everywhere, not just on mobile chat. And I don't see how this is confusing: RO is a permission, like moderator, not actually saying you _own_ a room.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 then why is it called “room ***owner***”?

Comment: Why is *what* called "room owner"? In any case, "mine" does imply ownership. Maybe "active" would be a better term. (I wouldn't call it a [bug], though..)

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer It's called Room Owner because Stack Exchange chat was intended to be an improvement over IRC, and the permission loosely corresponds to the IRC `+o` mode flag. (I would assume.)